# Groovy: Altering text of button when pressed

Tags: groovy

I am looking for a way to change the text of a button in Groovy when it is clicked. I can't find any documentation on it. I'm using Swingbuilder to lay the buttons out (it is for a Battleship game). I'm fairly new at using this lang.

What I'm using is:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.BorderLayout


class FrontEnd {
    FrontEnd() {
        def builder = new SwingBuilder()
        builder.edt {
            frame(title: 'Battleship', size: [500, 350], show: true, locationRelativeTo: null, resizable: false,
                defaultCloseOperation: WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {

                borderLayout(vgap: 5)

                panel(constraints: BorderLayout.CENTER) {
                    tableLayout {
                        tr {...
                        }
                        tr {
                            td {
                                label '1'
                            }
                            td {
                                button(id: 'a1', text: ' ', actionPerformed:)
                            }
                            td {
                                button(id: 'b1', text: ' ', actionPerformed:)
                            }
```

I don't know if it is even possible with this setup, so if there is another way I'd be glad to know about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example assigns a button to the variable `myButton` which is then used for reference. Clicking on the button will set the text to `hello 0`, `hello 1`, etc:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder 
import groovy.beans.Bindable 
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE 
import java.awt.*

class Example {
    static def count = 0

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def swingBuilder = new SwingBuilder()
        swingBuilder.edt {  
            frame(title: 'Example', size: [140, 80],
                  show: true, locationRelativeTo: null,
                  defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
                borderLayout(vgap: 5)

                panel(constraints: BorderLayout.SOUTH) {
                    myButton = button text: 'Save', actionPerformed: {
                        myButton.setText("hello ${count++}")
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. There is so little documented about Groovy, none of the examples I found used this structure. Really, thanks.